# How can I prevent a rows with a particular attribute from being deleted in a cascade?

Tags: sqlite, constraint, cascade

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS node (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  type TEXT CHECK(type IN ("DIRECTORY", "EXECUTABLE", "DOCUMENT")) NOT NULL,
  siblingOrder INTEGER NOT NULL,
  parentId INTEGER,
  protected INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  UNIQUE (parentId, siblingOrder) ON CONFLICT ABORT,
  FOREIGN KEY(parentId) REFERENCES node(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_parent 
    FOREIGN KEY (parentId)
    REFERENCES node(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I insert the following data

```
INSERT INTO node (id, name, type, siblingOrder, parentId, protected) 
VALUES 
(1, "DESKTOP", "DIRECTORY", 0, null, 1),
(2, "sys", "DIRECTORY", 1, 1, 0),
(3, "dont delete me", "DIRECTORY", 2, 2, 1);
```

I run the following command

```
DELETE FROM node 
WHERE id=2;
```

How can I prevent records being deleted that have a `protected` value of `TRUE`? (In this case, I don't want the "don't delete me" record to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign Key actions are *all or nothing*, and therefore there's no way to achieve what you're looking for with how you defined your Foreign Key constraint.

Instead you can change the `ON DELETE` action to `NO ACTION` such that a delete doesn't cascade ever, and you can define a [`DELETE` Trigger](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to check if the record is `protected` and do the `DELETE` when it isn't.

Comment: Or raise an error if the delete trigger detects protected=1